# Passing MVC Model Data to Client-side TypeScript Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, model, typescript

When using MVC, I sometimes pass the server's model data to the client-side JavaScript by using Razor injected into the JavaScript, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myClientGuid = '@Model.MyServerGuid';
</script>
```

This sets a JavaScript variable named `myClientGuid` to the value of the server-side model property `MyServerGuid`. When it reaches the client, the code looks something like this inside the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myClientGuid = 'EF0077AB-0482-4D91-90A7-75285F01CA6F';
</script>
```

This allows external JavaScript files to use this variable.

My question is, in TypeScript, since  *all* code must be referenced via external files, what is the best way to pass server-side fields to TypeScript code? External code files cannot contain Razor code. Should I use the same technique as above, in the View, mixing JavaScript and Typescript within the project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler just needs to know that your server-side fields exist. The easiest way to do that is to use ambient declarations (see section 10 of the spec). For example, if you had a .ts file that needed to use myClientGuid, you could do

```
declare var myClientGuid: string;
```

at the top of your main .ts file. The compiler will not generate code for this var declaration, so you won't clobber anything. Now any files that reference that .ts file will know that there is a myClientGuid string available in global scope.

Comment: Interesting. Any suggestions on how to do this is you don't want to add the variable directly to the window object to avoid pollution?

Comment: Far out, I have been pulling my hair out trying to work out what the correct way to do this is and finally found something that makes some sense. Thank you!

@stvn I would think that you could create a single global object that holds your config parameters and that mostly avoids poluting the global namespace too much as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (to avoid global variables) is to wrap the TypeScript code in a function that takes the needed server-side fields as parameters:

In TypeScript file:

```
function setupMyPage(myGuid:string) {
   ...
}
```

In .cshtml:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("<path-to-typescript>")'></script>
<script>
    setupMyPage('@Model.MyServerGuid');
</script>
```

If you are using RequireJS, you can also export the `setupMyPage` function as a module, to avoid adding the function to global namespace:

In TypeScript file:

```
export = setupMyPage;
```

In .cshtml:

```
<script>
    require(['@Url.Content("<path-to-typescript>")'], function(setupMyPage) {
        setupMyPage('@Model.MyServerGuid');
    };
</script>
```